# why cdev_add does not do something like device_add/kobject_add of driver/base/core.c

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

In what manner a character device registration is different from other device registration??

Here is a platform driver registering device with regulator core which in turn with driver core :
/drivers/regulator/tps65086-regulator.c--->/drivers/regulator/core.c---> drivers/base/core.c

call flow :
 tps65086_regulator_probe-->regulator_register---> device_register--->device_add---> kobject_add

where as below is a driver which registers device as a character device

/drivers/scsi/3w-xxxx.c -->fs/char_dev.c ---> /drivers/base/map.c

call flow:

tw_probe-->register_chrdev --> cdev_add --> kobj_map

why not this finally going to driver core and calls device_add ??

Answer (score 0):

The difference between platform driver and a device driver is that the platform devices connected directly to the CPU, while device drivers handle devices connected to the system bus. So there registration mechanisms are also different.

For example, platform devices will register with the platform bus, which is a pseudo bus. While actual devices will register with there respective busses to which the device are attached.